# List posts of term on term's admin edit page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Is there any way to list what posts are attached to the term on the term page in the admin?

I have a post type of 'Banners' and a taxonomy of 'Banner groups'. You can assign banners to the banner group like a tag.

What I want, is when editing the banner group, seeing all the posts that are attached to this term.

I can't seem to find any documentation for this anywhere

Comment: On the tag page in admin, you can see the count column, that links to all the posts attached to this term.

Comment: Fantastic – I didn't even notice the count!

Answer (score 1):

> On the tag page in admin, you can see the count column, that links to
>   all the posts attached to this term

Thanks to [@Pooja Mistry](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/71675/pooja-mistry) for answering this